# How to disable the highlight control state of a UIButton?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uibutton, uikit, uicontrol

I've got a UIButton that, when selected, shouldn't change state when being touched.
The default behaviour is for it to be in UIControlStateHighlighted while being touched, and this is making me angry.

Suggestions?

Comment: You should meditate :-P

Answer (score 335, accepted):

Your button must have its `buttonType` set to Custom.

In IB you can uncheck "Highlight adjusts image".

Programmatically you can use `theButton.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = NO;`

Similar options are available for the "disabled" state as well.

Comment: Any chance you know what the programmatic version of this would be?
Right now I've got it working hackishly by making it disabled, and dressing it up as being selected.

Comment: uibutton.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = NO;

Comment: Also make sure the button type is set to CUSTOM. (As Mosib Asad mentioned in another answer)

Comment: Great!!! just a little and obvious change that i missed!!! I had set UIButton class type to MyCustomClass but forghet to change this one. So it was giving unselected button highlighted effect. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 41):

In addition to above answer of unchecking "highlight adjusts image" in IB, make sure that button type is set CUSTOM.

Comment: This was the missing piece: button type CUSTOM. Thanx!

Comment: What if i would like to keep as a System UIButton? can't i remove the highlight adjusts image?

Answer (score 39):

This will work for you:

```
[button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button_image"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button_image_selected"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button_image_selected"] forState:UIControlStateSelected | UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

3rd line is the trick here...

This works the same for setting image/backgroundImage

Comment: This works perfect for me. The `adjustsImageWhenHighlighted` property of `UIButton` seems to affect only the background image.

Comment: Be aware, that if do decide to assign an image to the 'disabled state', you do not call setBackgroundImage. Instead, you should do the following

[button setImage:image forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
Also also be aware, that as is mentioned in this thread, the adjustsImageWhenHighlighted UIButton property only effects the background image.

Comment: this wonderful answer should be referenced if your purpose is to remove the control's Highlight state , not only remove the highlight effect on click

Answer (score 28):

```
adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = NO;
```

Answer (score 23):

```
button.adjustsImageWhenDisabled = NO;
```

is equally useful for having your own appearance of a disabled button.

Answer (score 5):

Depending on what changes from the default to the highlighted state of the button, you can call a couple of methods to set them to what you need. So if the image changes you can do

```
[myButton setImage:[myButton imageForState:UIControlStateNormal] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

If the text changes you can do

```
[myButton setTitle:[myButton titleForState:UIControlStateNormal] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

other similar functions:

`- (void)setTitleColor:(UIColor *)color forState:(UIControlState)state`

`- (void)setTitleShadowColor:(UIColor *)color forState:(UIControlState)state`

Comment: setTitleColor is all i needed to disable highlight on uibutton's text

Answer (score 5):

**For Swifty Developer -**

```
yourButton.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = false
```

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 3+**

```
button.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = false

button.adjustsImageWhenDisabled = false
```

Answer (score 3):

OK here's an easy solution if this works for you, after a week of banging my head on this it finally occurred to me to just set highlighted=NO for the 1st line of the IBAction method for the TouchUpInside or TouchDown, or whatever works. For me it was fine on the TouchUpInside.

```
-(IBAction)selfDismiss:(id)sender {

    self.btnImage.highlighted = NO;

    NSLog(@"selfDismiss");

    etc, etc, etc.

}
```

Answer (score 3):

make your button Type - "Custom"
and Uncheck - Highlighted Adjust image and 
you are done.

Answer (score 2):

just two things:

```
UIButton *btnTransparentComponent = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
btnTransparentComponent.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = NO;
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue and found that "unchecking" Clears Graphic Content in interface builder fixed my issue

[image]

Answer (score 1):

After the introduction of `Style`, you have to set the style to `Default` in IB along with setting the type to `Custom` to be able to disable the highlighting effect completely. Otherwise your button text will keep highlighting.

*Setting the `Style` to `Default` resets the text color to white.

Answer (score -4):

avoid to set UIButton's **Line Break** to **Clip**, use instead the standard **Truncate Middle**

[image]