# Disable highlighted UIControl state of a UIButton

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uibutton

I have a `UIButton`, I want to disable its `UIControlStateHighlighted` if the button is in selected state. With that I mean, if the current state of `UIButton` is `ControlStateSelected` then on touch down, its state should not change to highlighted which is the default behavior of a `UIButton`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable the highlight control state of a UIButton?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2259905/how-to-disable-the-highlight-control-state-of-a-uibutton)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
[button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button_image"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button_image_selected"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button_image_selected"] forState:UIControlStateSelected | UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

Third line is the trick here, it will disable the highlighted state of UIButton if button is already in Selected State

Comment: this wonderful answer should be referenced if your purpose is to remove the control's Highlight state , not only remove the highlight effect on click

Answer (score 9):

Uncheck "highlight adjusts image" in IB, Also make sure that button type is set CUSTOM in IB

Answer (score 3):

```
if(button.selected == YES)
button.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = NO;
else
button.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = YES;
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. But even after setting utton.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = NO; highlighted state is evoked

Answer (score 1):

just two things:

```
UIButton *btnTransparentComponent = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
btnTransparentComponent.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = NO;
```