# How to disable UIButton highlight on click?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

How to disable button highlight effect on click? Have custom button with white bg color and DarkGray text color. The problem is the text becomes white on button click. Already tried but none of them worked:

a. Did uncheck "Highlighted Ajusts Image" in interface builder.

b. Tried setting highlighted = NO in button pressed method:

```
((UIButton *)sender).highlighted = NO
```

c. Tried setting the same title for highlihted state:

```
[button setTitle:[button titleForState:UIControlStateNormal] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you using storyboards.

Comment: when you say highlight effect, you mean that the text changes its colour?

Comment: Also are you using an image for your button?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

UIButton will highlighted on click, so check button setting
Change the title color in highlight state config to same as default state
Or you can set:

```
[button setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

If you want to control Highlighted by code, you can disable normal highlighted by subclass Button and disable in touchesBegin:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    if (self.state == UIControlStateHighlighted) {
        [self setHighlighted:NO];
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2259905/how-to-disable-the-highlight-control-state-of-a-uibutton

Answer (score 47):

You could also make the UIButton type : custom from StoryBoard

[image: Custom button]

This should strip down any system behavior for you. (I think)

Comment: After quite some searching I came upon your answer. Adds an important aspect which solved my problem: The Type=System behavior will add a fade effect to the highlighted background image and text. Switching to Type=Custom will disable this effect so that exactly the colors specified will be displayed. Thanks!

Comment: this does not when using images

Comment: This is the answer

Answer (score 25):

This is a solution for buttons that have images. In the storyboard, there is a property called `HighlightedAdjustsImage` which is On by default. Disable that and your button image will not show any highlighted properties.

Answer (score 22):

> **Swift 4 with XCode 9**

Just uncheck **"Highlighted Adjust Image"** and if you want to remove disabled background uncheck **"Disabled Adjust Image"** too.

> First ensure your button type is **"Custom"**

[image]

Answer (score 12):

old outdated answers, and old question, but the newest and easiest way is:

```
    overlayButton.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = false
```

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer, worked perfectly.

Answer (score 7):

None of the solutions I found online worked for me (including these ones listed here), so I ended up doing this in my **custom `UIButton` subclass**:

```
// swift:

override var isHighlighted: Bool {
    didSet { if isHighlighted { isHighlighted = false } }
}
```

I also have the `buttonType` set to `.custom`, but it probably makes no difference here.

And now: no more weird highlighting or colour animations!

Answer (score 3):

My 2 cents ;) Swift 3 ready

```
class CustomButton: UIButton {

    override var isHighlighted: Bool {
        didSet {
            if (isHighlighted) {
                super.isHighlighted = false
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**Situation and History**

I had set images for `UIControlState.normal` and `UIControlState.selected`, so setting `UIButton.isSelected = true` shows selected image, else the normal image.

The issue we discovered was when `UIButton.isSelected = true`, and during highlight/focus *(by tap hold the button and discard tap by swiping away)* button shows image for `UIControlState.normal`, that looked pretty ugly to my boss :D

I tried several solutions, such as `UIButton(type: UIButtonType.custom)` and `UIButton.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = false`, none helped :(

Answer (score 3):

> **You can do it by creating extension in Swift 4.2**

```
extension UIButton {
open override var isHighlighted: Bool {
    didSet {
        super.isHighlighted = false
    }
}}
```

Answer (score -1):

I had this issue in a tableview and what resolved it for me was in `cellForRowAt indexPath` add the following:

For Swift 3 and above:

```
cell.selectionStyle = .none
```

Now when I click on the cell I no longer get a grey overlay on my cell.