# How to disable title highlight color when apply Plain style in UIButton?

Tags: ios, uibutton, uikit

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2259905/how-to-disable-the-highlight-control-state-of-a-uibutton) and try to change the type to custom, it works when I config the button in old way(button's style is default), but when I apply the plain style introduced from iOS 15 I can notice the color changed, is there a way to disable it? I have also tried `adjustsImageWhenHighlighted` or `showsTouchWhenHighlighted` but they don't work too.
[image]

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use the "Default" style `UIButton`? Or are you just asking how to do it with the iOS 15+ "configuration" buttons?

Comment: @DonMag There is no special reason, I just want to try the new API and hope to find a way can disable that behavior with new configuration API.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this via the configuration's `.titleTextAttributesTransformer`.

If you have added a Plain style button in Storyboard, and you want the title to be - for example - `.systemRed` with **NO** change for state, you can do this:

```
    var config = storyboardButton.configuration
    
    // use only .systemRed for title color (in all states)
    config?.titleTextAttributesTransformer = UIConfigurationTextAttributesTransformer { incoming in
        var outgoing = incoming
        outgoing.foregroundColor = UIColor.systemRed
        return outgoing
    }
    
    storyboardButton.configuration = config
```

Similar approach for code-created button:

```
    var cfg = UIButton.Configuration.plain()

    // use only .systemGreen for title color (in all states)
    cfg.titleTextAttributesTransformer = UIConfigurationTextAttributesTransformer { incoming in
        var outgoing = incoming
        outgoing.foregroundColor = UIColor.systemGreen
        return outgoing
    }
    
    cfg.title = "Code Button"

    let codeButton = UIButton()
    codeButton.configuration = cfg
```

For more flexibility, you can subclass `UIButton` like this:

```
class CustomHighlightButton: UIButton {
    
    var normalColor: UIColor = .systemRed
    var highlightColor: UIColor = .systemGreen
    
    override func updateConfiguration() {
        guard let cfg = configuration else {
            return
        }
        
        var updatedCfg = cfg
        
        let newTitleColor: UIColor
        
        switch self.state {
        case .highlighted:
            newTitleColor = highlightColor
        default:
            newTitleColor = normalColor
        }
        
        updatedCfg.titleTextAttributesTransformer = UIConfigurationTextAttributesTransformer { incoming in
            var i = incoming
            i.foregroundColor = newTitleColor
            return i
        }
        
        self.configuration = updatedCfg
    }
}
```

Then implement it like this:

```
    let customButton = CustomHighlightButton()
    var cfg = UIButton.Configuration.plain()
    cfg.title = "Custom Highlight Button"
    customButton.configuration = cfg

    // use only .systemBlue for title color (in all states)
    customButton.normalColor = .systemBlue
    customButton.highlightColor = .systemBlue
```

or:

```
    // use .systemBlue for title color - highlighted state
    customButton.highlightColor = .systemBlue
    // use .systemRed for title color - all other states
    customButton.normalColor = .systemRed
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed reply! I used titleTextAttributesTransformer and it works as expected.